# How to extract specific rows of a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a csv excel file that contains two columns named, "year_mo" and "vehicle_class".

```
year_mo, vehicle_class
2010-01, Category A
2010-02, Category B
2010-03, Category C
2011-01, Category A
2011-02, Category B
2011-03, Category C
2011-04, Category D
2011-05, Category E
```

I am using genfromtxt to load the file into my jupyter notebook. My goal is to extract all the rows that start from "2010". However, I am unable to do so. Below are my codes:

```
filename = "demoResults.csv"
data = np.genfromtxt(filename,
            dtype=["U50","U50"], delimiter="," ,names=True)

year = data["year_mo"]
year_2010 = year["2010" in year]
print(year_2010)
```

The result will print out an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does: `"2010" in year`

What you need to do is to check each element in the array:

```
year_2010 = [y for y in years if "2010" in y]
```

Comment: Hi Sir, is there a way to do it, without the use of a loop?

Comment: You need to have a loop, the issue is that you need to do the `in` inside this loop, and list comprehensions are the easiest way of doing so (IMHO).

Comment: Oh, I see, is there another method besides using the in operator? The reason why I used it is that my python knowledge scope is still quite small.

Comment: The in operator is the best option if you want to check that a string is inside another one. There is a method to do that also on the string object, but it's less Pythonic.

Comment: Oh, I see, Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi Matthieu, I just realised that my goal is to extract out all the rows that start from 2010. For example,           Category A 2010-01, Category B 2010-02,Category C 2010-03 . However, the code that you provided only prints out 2010-01, 2010-02,2010-03

Comment: OK, in that case, use `[i for i, y in enumerate(years) if "2010" in y]`

Comment: Hi Matthieu, I need further assistance. Is it okay if we chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185144/discussion-between-issaki-and-matthieu-brucher